# Convert Java method Base64.encodeToString() to PHP

Tags: java, php, base64, byte

Hello I have the below java code:

```
Base64.encodeToString(("users name").getBytes(), 2);
```

And I'm trying to convert it to php:

```
bytesEnc("users name");

function bytesEnc($string) {
    $bytes = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
        $bytes[] = ord($string[$i]);
    }
    return $bytes;
}
```

I converted `getBytes()` but I don't know what to do next. I know function `base64_encode` exists inn PHP but the second argument of `encodetoString` java method with value 2 bothers me.
Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString(byte[],%20int)) the second parameter is a bitwise flag.

If the value is 2, then the flag `NO_WRAP` is used:

> Encoder flag bit to omit all line terminators (i.e., the output will be on one long line).

This means its removes the new lines.

```
function bytesEnc($string){
  $string = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $string);

  $bytes = array();
  for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string) - 1; $i++){
    $bytes[] = ord($string[$i]);
  }
  return $bytes;
}

echo base64_encode(implode('',bytesEnc('users name')));
```